# Upload Images/ Files in MVC4 SinglePageApplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an MVC4 SPA application. One of features is able to upload files/images and store in database. I wonder how to do this. Can we handle the same way with normal MVC or Asp.net? This is my model:

```
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public byte[] Binary { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OtherInfo { get; set; }
```

Please share me some demo/tutorial if possible...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar and ended up using the Telerik MVC components (open source version).

The upload control is extremely easy to use in that suite.

Comment: Hi Ed DeGagne... I found uploading demo of telerik at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/upload .... following this demo, I think telerik will store files/images into physical folder, won't it? What about storing into database? Can you help me please?

Comment: Rocky, you're going to have to write that code yourself, the component won't handle any of that for you. Plenty of code samples out there to store images in a database. The event you specified to handle the upload is the plcae you want to handle the storage code.

Comment: @Ed DeGagne, where can we download the open source version of Telerik MVC? I only found some KendoUI.

Comment: Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC is the successor of Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC. Telerik Extensions are in a maintenance phase and will be actively supported (bugfixes and minor enhancements primarily) till Q2 2013.